# Maven plugin - updateSql and outputDefaultSchema

Tags: liquibase

I need to produce schema prefixed SQL queries in the generated SQL files. It looks like the following configuration has no effect:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
  <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.8</version>
  <configuration>
    <defaultSchemaName>FOO</defaultSchemaName>
    <defaultCatalogName>FOO</defaultCatalogName>
    <outputDefaultSchema>true</outputDefaultSchema>
    <outputDefaultCatalog>true</outputDefaultCatalog>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>buildSQL</id>
        <phase>process-resources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>buildSQL</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

I would expect the following e.g.

```
<modifyDataType tableName="BAR" columnName="xyz" newDataType="varchar(255)" />
```

to produce

```
ALTER TABLE FOO.BAR MODIFY xyz varchar(255);
```

but this is produced instead

```
ALTER TABLE BAR MODIFY xyz varchar(255);
```

Any idea how to make Liquibase produce FOO.BAR?

Comment: Which database do you use (resp. let liquibase run against)?

Comment: It runs against Oracle 11g

Comment: Just to make sure: Are you using the current most version of liquibase just like your scripts states? E.g. 3.0.8?
There has been a problem (reported with oracle and db2 databases) up to version 3.0.2 in liquibase. See Jira Ticket [CORE-1301](https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-1301).

Comment: I'm aware of that, so I've upgraded to 3.0.8, it was 3.0.2 prior to that. In fact, "outputDefaultSchema" was added in 3.0.3.

Comment: Ok - you did not write anything about it - so it was a guess.
I do not have any oracle db available so I can only give you more hints on what you could try. 
So can you try to put `outputDefaultCatalog` to `false` and then see if it changes anything?

Comment: I have tried that. I have tried everything :)

Comment: Sorry, then I guess I can't help. If you really tried all kinds of combinations and nothing changes then something else (somewhere else) is wrong.

Comment: It appears to be a bug. https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-1748 There is a pull requestthat will be part of 3.2.0